# jquery javascript reset array to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This question has been edited greatly,
I need to reset this code with a reset button so I can use it again from currentItem 1,the problem is that only the current item is reset and the highlighted list items are still set as if the current item was not at 1.

```
 var stuff = new Array();
stuff["li_1"]="ext_1";
stuff["li_2"]="hc_1";
stuff["li_3"]="ext_2";
stuff["li_4"]="ext_3";
stuff["li_5"]="hc_2";
stuff["li_6"]="ext_4";
stuff["li_7"]="hc_3";
stuff["li_8"]="ext_5";
stuff["li_9"]="hc_4";
stuff["li_10"]="ext_6";
stuff["li_11"]="hc_5";      
var currentItem=1;  
var extWrong=false;
var extCorrect=false;
var hcWrong=false;
var hcCorrect=false;

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
    $('#li_1').draggable({revert:true} );
    $("#li_1").addClass("highlighted");
    $('.drop_area').droppable({
         tolerance:"pointer",
         drop:function (event, ui) {
            var tmpID=$(ui.draggable).attr("id");
            var droppableID = $(this).attr("id");
            var audioToPlay="";
            $("#" + tmpID).hide();           
            $("#" + stuff[tmpID]).show();
            $("#" + stuff[tmpID]).addClass("highlighted");

            currentItem++;

            var dragType=tmpID.split("_")[1];
            dragType=(dragType=="1" || dragType=="3" ||dragType=="4" ||dragType=="6" ||dragType=="8" ||dragType=="10")?"ext":"hc";
            var dropType=droppableID=="extreme_thoughts"?"ext":"hc";

            if(dragType=="ext" && dropType=="ext"){
                    audioToPlay=extCorrect==false?"IntDragDrop_ExtremeCorrect.mp3":"ding.mp3";
                    extCorrect=true;
            }else if(dragType=="ext" && dropType=="hc"){
                    audioToPlay=extWrong==false?"IntDragDrop_ExtremeIncorrect.mp3":"pop4c.mp3";
                    extWrong=true;
            }else if(dragType=="hc" && dropType=="hc"){
                    audioToPlay=hcCorrect==false?"IntDragDrop_HealthyCorrect.mp3":"ding.mp3";
                    hcCorrect=true;
            }else if(dragType=="hc" && dropType=="ext"){
                audioToPlay=hcWrong==false?"IntDragDrop_HealthyIncorrect.mp3":"pop4c.mp3";
                    hcWrong=true;

            }
            playSound(audioToPlay,"#" + stuff[tmpID],"#" + "li_" + currentItem);

            }

    });
```

here is my broken button.

```
$("#restart").click(function(){
  currentItem=1;
    var extWrong=false;
    var extCorrect=false;
    var hcWrong=false;
    var hcCorrect=false;
  $("#ext_1,#ext_2,#ext_3,#ext_4,#ext_5,#ext_6,#hc_1,#hc_2,#hc_3,#hc_4,#hc_5,#congrats").hide()
  $("#li_1,#li_2,#li_3,#li_4,#li_5,#li_6,#li_7,#li_8,#li_9,#li_10,#li_11,#hide_me,#hide_me2").show()
  $("#li_2,#li_3,#li_4,#li_5,#li_6,#li_7,#li_8,#li_9,#li_10,#li_11").removeClass("highlighted");
    alert(currentItem)
});
```

Comment: `currentItem` doesn't look like an array to me.

Comment: Your second line of code also has `currentItem == 1;`, using `==` and not `=`, so that line is just going to evaluate to a boolean and have nothing else happen (no assignment is done).

Comment: I wonder what it would be then. It holds a value that changes, how might I reset a var then?

Comment: I have also tryed currentItm=1

Comment: Then I think we need more code. For instance (as @j08691 indicated originally), there is no array in the code you've given us, but you are talking about some array somewhere in your code.

Comment: Well I was able to reset the var to 1 now, but something else is wrong, I would delete this post for now if I could.'

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your assignment, you're doing `currentItem==1` instead of `currentItem=1`;

Comment: Edited, that was something I tried before resorting to the stack, just forgot to change it back to one "="